# Maximum cardinality affinely independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $S$ is affinely independent. Then
$$|S| \le n + 1.$$
Why? (e.g. does anybody know some place where this is proven?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a first step of a proof, we could use the following lemma 1.

$\textbf{Lemma 1}$.
Let $1 \le |S|$.
We define $r := |S| - 1$.
By $s_0, s_1, \dots, s_r$ we denote the elements of $S$.
We consider the family
$$F := \{s_1 - s_0, \; s_2 - s_0, \; \dots, \; s_r - s_0\};$$
please note that $F$ is empty if $r = 0$.
The family $F$ is linearly independent.

$\textit{Proof}$.
We prove by contradiction.
To that end, we assume that $F$ is linearly dependent.
Therefore, there is a vector $(s_j - s_0) \in F$
which is a linear combination of the other vectors $(s_i - s_0)$ in $F$;
i.e. of the vectors $(s_i - s_0)$ for which $i \in I$,
where $I := \{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 1 \le x \le r,\; x \ne j\}$.
Thus, we have the equation
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
s_j - s_0 = & \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i (s_i - s_0) \, ,
 \quad \quad \text{where each }\alpha_i\text{ is some real number.}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
We rearrange the equation as follows.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
s_j - s_0 = & \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i s_i - \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i s_0 \\
s_j - s_0 = & \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i s_i - \left(\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i\right) s_0 \\
s_j       = & \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i s_i - \left(\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i - 1\right) s_0  \\
s_j       = & \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i s_i + \left(1 - \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i \right) s_0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
We examine the last equation.
Obviously, the right-hand side is a linear combination
of $s_0$ and all the vectors $s_i$.
Obviously, the coefficients of this linear combination sum up to $1$.
Thus, the linear combination is an affine combination.
Thereby, we finally observe that $s_j$,
which is an element of $S$,
is an affine combination
of the other elements in $S$.
Therefore, $S$ is not affinely independent.
This contradicts the definition of $S$.
Hence, our assumption ($F$ $\textit{is linearly dependent}$) is false.
Hence, $F$ is linearly independent.

QED

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_r\}\subset S$, then the family $\{\vec{s_0s_1},\ldots,\vec{s_0s_r}\}$ is linearly independent in the vector space $\Bbb R^n$, hence $r\leq n$.
So $S$ contains at most $n + 1$ elements.

Comment: I spent some long time trying to understand your first step. I wrote a proof for it in my answer below. Perhaps you would like to take a look at it.